# How do I set a static IP address in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ipv4

If I do not have access to the router / DHCP server to create a static reservation (i.e. asking the router / DHCP server to set aside a specific IP address when a certain MAC address requests it), how can I set my Windows 7 workstation to have a static IPv4 address?

Comment: Will you use the IP that DHCP already gave you? There are some strategies to choose an IP that most likely will not handed out to anyone else, or better, not at all. (choosing one high in the IP range, or one that is not within the range of the DHCP server pool. It can involce some guesswork though :)

Comment: @lexib0y add any awesome information you can!

Comment: It would help if you could give the current IP address, netmask and gateway, because some educated guessing is needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click on **Start**, then **Control Panel**
2. Choose **Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center** (or just **Network and Sharing Center**)
3. Click **Change Adapter Settings** on the left
4. Find the network adapter (NIC) that you are currently connecting with. Right-click it and click **Properties** (requires Admin access)
5. Choose **Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)** and choose **Properties**
   [image]
6. Choose the option to **Use the following IP address:** and fill in the blanks for your network.
   [image]
7. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>, and close the next window. Verify you can access the Internet.

You will now have the IP Address *always* set to this address. Because it is getting set to whatever was found below, once your computers find the new address, it will remember it. Your router (more specifically, the DNS Service) will match the name with the IP Address, and HomeGroups are built to just know (using IPv6, usually).

## How do you find out what you can put here?

1. Click on **Start**, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up the *Command Prompt*.
2. Type `ipconfig /all` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Check for the following items:

   ```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.xxx
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.xxx
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.xxx
   ```

   Your screen will output different numbers. Keep the information handy, and put them into the dialog above.
4. Type `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [NETSH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx) command to do this.

### Setting static IP address:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="network_name" static 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254
                                                          ^ IP Address ^ Subnet Mask ^ Default Gateway
```

### Setting Primary & Seconday DNS

```
netsh interface ip set dns name=”Local Area Connection” static 192.168.0.250
netsh interface ip add dns name=”Local Area Connection” 8.8.8.8 index=2
```