# How to force a single application to avoid a VPN tunnel and just use the LAN?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, vpn, lan

I have two laptop computers on my local wireless network, and I control them both with Mouse Without Borders. It works fine, and the computers locate each other by name.

When I start Cisco VPN on both computers to connect to my work VPN, Mouse Without Borders stops working, because it can no longer communicate over the local network.

I do want *all other* traffic to go over the VPN, but I want Mouse Without Borders to stay off the VPN, so the computers using it can still communicate through it over the local wireless network. Obviously, the Mouse Without Borders instances on each machine cannot connect to each other if their traffic goes over the VPN.

How can I do this easily in Windows 10?  Seems like a simple request to have a specific program avoid the Cisco VPN route and just stay on the local network.

---

Relevant, but not helpful/obsolete: [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network)
Relevant, but not helpful; may require multiple network cards: https://superuser.com/a/1484402/50147

Comment: Found one solution. Don't use Cisco VPN. Use OpenConnect-GUI instead. It's fully compatible with Cisco's VPNs, and everything "just worked" out of the box. Mouse without borders continues to work, regardless of whether VPN is active, and no matter which machines are on or off VPN. It's wonderful. It doesn't do any of the bullshit "route table babysitting" that Cisco's client does, and it's more secure. Cisco's client actually monitors for and interferes with manual changes you make to the routing table, which is insane.

Comment: Cisco Anyconnect is a security product. Not just a plain old VPN. So all of the “bullshit” is actually policy enforced by your place of employment. At best you are introducing a security risk to your organization, at worst you are violating company policy and gearing up for a reprimand.